# Shell script: Text files to array

Tags: text-processing, array

I must use C-shell. I have a 40+ list of ip and hostname in text file.

```
sat1 100.34.54.65
sat2 100.34.54.55
sat3 100.34.54.45
and so on..
```

i want to set the ip and hostname as list of array. The first array is hostname ; sat1 sat2 sat3 and second array the ip address.For example:

array1 = (sat1 sat2 sat3)
array2 = (100.34.54.65 100.34.54.55 100.34.54.45)

how to make the ip and hostname from the .txt file to list of array?

Comment: What are you actually trying to solve here?  This sounds like the XY problem.  For instance, if what you want is to be able to look up the data later in a script, you could just use `awk`.

Comment: one of the disadvantages of using csh for scripting (apart from the fact that it is buggy) is that hardly anyone else uses it for scripting (and almost no experts do).....so finding documentation, examples, tutorials etc or getting high-quality help with it is difficult.   As has been mentioned, awk is a far better language for this task.  perl would be as good.  bash or ksh would be better than csh.

Comment: name=( $(awk '{print $2}' ./yosh.txt) ) ...whats wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0
while IFS= read -r line; do
array1[i]="${line:0:4}"
array2[i]="${line:5:12}"
#echo ${array1[i]} ${array2[i]}
i=$((i + 1))
done <$1
```

for every line it reads it will slice it and store it into the eq. array slot. I didnt add the echos for arrayX[i] but you can test that. I hope this works for you.

Comment: I just saw you wanted this in csh, apologies!

Comment: do you have idea in csh?

Comment: This script assumes fixed hostname (and thus line) length. What if a line is "hellothereIamLoopback 127.0.0.1" ?

Comment: the script assume the hostname have fixed leghth